How do I know if a word in the English translation is implied by the Hebrew or Greek, or specifically stated?
I understand that one way to know is if an English translation like the NKJV or NASB has words in italics. Then I can know that the English word is implied rather than actually stated in the original Hebrew or Greek.
But, let's take an example like Genesis 15:6, which I have been studying. In the verse, the Hebrew word used for "then he believed" is wə·he·’ĕ·min.
Bible Hub (which I've just switched to from Blue Letter Bible) tells me that this is the only occurrence of this Hebrew form of the root word 'āman.
Does this mean that there is only one occurrence of "believe" used in this specific form? Or does it mean that there is only occurrence of "then he believed" in this specific form?
In other words, is "then" and "he" in the Hebrew, or are they just implied?

PLEASE read a good Hebrew grammar - we are not going to school you in the myriad subtleties of Hebrew grammar here.  Suffice to say that the word in Gen 15:6 is the grammatical form, Verb-Hifil-Conjuctive Perfect-3rd person masculine singular, ie, with an implies "he".  It also has a waw = "and" or "then".

@Dottard, yes, I'm motivated to gain at least some rudimentary understanding of Hebrew grammar.

The general question you are asking would require extensive detail when it comes to Hebrew.  For example, Hebrew has imperfect and perfect tense, not past, present, and future tense.  Present tense meaning is usually expressed with a participle or a adjective with a present being verb understood when translated.  But, that doesn't cover Genesis 15:6.
So, I will limit the rest of the answer to וְהֶאֱמִ֖ן in Genesis 15:6.  Technically there are no understood words translating this verb.  The conjunction וְ is prefixed to the verb and is translated and or then in some translations.  He is part of the meaning of the verb.   הֶאֱמִ֖ן is hiphil perfect 3rd person masculine singular.  Thus, he is contained in the meaning of the verb.  Perfect in Hebrew means completed action and in Genesis 15:6 means past tense.
Your struggle with הֶאֱמִ֖ן is understanding the hiphil.  The root of the verb is אמן where we the word amen, translated trulyTf this verb form only occurs in the passive participle in the Hebrew Old Testament (the Tanakh).  The niphal in this verb means "to prove to be firm, reliable, faithful ... —to be permanent, to endure" {Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament (electronic ed., p. 63). E.J. Brill.}  The hiphil (the case here) means "—1. to believe = to think ... —2. to regard something as trustworthy, to believe in ...  —3. to have trust in, to believe in, God: with בְּ ..." (Ibid., p. 64).
This probably raises more questions for you, but hopefully this will give you some idea of what you are dealing with.

+1 Thanks for the terrific answer, @Perry! Languages can be frustrating and confusing. It's very helpful to understand what we're up against! @Luke, comparing several more-literal translations into English helps reveal the controversies and choices made by the experts. Still, I agree that it's interesting to be able to at least understand the reasoning behind such choices.

Yes, thank you very much @Perry. That is very helpful to know that the hiphil perfect 3rd person masculine singular indicates that "he" should be included in the translation.
And thank you for including an answer to another question I posted recently. I've been learning a bit about Hebrew verb stems since then, and your explanation of hiphil confirms what I've seen explained elsewhere.
